# Column "Feedback_id" is amgiuous when generating limit query with nestjs/crud & typeorm

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am using nestjs/crud with a model to which a view is connected.

When doing a query with `?limit=` param, Typeorm generates a query containing two select params for the same column name:

```sql
SELECT 
  DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."Feedback_id" as "ids_Feedback_id" 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      "Feedback"."id" AS "Feedback_id", 
      "Feedback"."id" AS "Feedback_id", 
...
```

What causes this and how to get rid of the duplicate param?

This is the related issue https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/777

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade typeorm to 0.2.45 fixed the issue